# Excel file got issues reading Tamil letters

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When I insert tamil letters into excel cell, instead of appearing like this: அண்ணன், it appears as [image]

Why is it so? How do I avoid this?

Comment: Tried different font? I just tested in Excel 2013 with Calibri, and it displays properly.

Comment: tried different fonts, still the same.